# Floating Rational type error calculating sqrt

Tags: haskell

When I ask GHCi for the  golden section, I get the correct answer:

```
Prelude> (-1 + sqrt 5) / 2
0.6180339887498949
```

Doing the same inside "xmonad.hs" (for tiling), I receive:

```
xmonad.hs:32:22: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Rational) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘sqrt 5’
      In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(- 1 + sqrt 5)’
      In the expression: (- 1 + sqrt 5) / 2
```

What happens here, what helps?

Comment: What modules do you have imported in `xmonad.hs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask GHCi for the value of this expression and request a `Rational` result, you get the same error:

```
Prelude> (-1 + sqrt 5) / 2 :: Rational

<interactive>:1:7: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Rational) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘sqrt 5’
      In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(- 1 + sqrt 5)’
      In the expression: (- 1 + sqrt 5) / 2 :: Rational
Prelude>
```

The issue is that the `Rational` type doesn't have a `Floating` instance, and you appear to be using the expression `(-1 + sqrt 5) / 2` in a context where a `Rational` is expected.

This makes sense.  The `Rational` type is intended to represent exact calculations on rational numbers, and there is no exact rational representation of this expression.

The `Data.Ratio` package includes the `approxRational` function to get a nearby rational approximation to a non-rational expression, so you should be able to write:

```
approxRational ((-1 + sqrt 5) / 2) 0.001
```

to get a rational that's within 0.001 of your desired result:

```
Prelude> import Data.Ratio
Prelude Data.Ratio> approxRational ((-1 + sqrt 5) / 2) 0.001
21 % 34
```

Comment: Tiling is still 50/50, but the code compiles and I fully understand what I am doing. Thanks!